# Why a local variable is used instead of var parameter in a procedure?

Tags: delphi

oIn Delphi SysUtils is a `ScanBlanks` procedure:

```
procedure ScanBlanks(const S: string; var Pos: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  I := Pos;
  while (I <= Length(S)) and (S[I] = ' ') do Inc(I);
  Pos := I;
end;
```

I wonder why the procedure is using `I` variable. Can't we use use `Pos` var directly?

```
procedure ScanBlanks(const S: string; var Pos: Integer);
begin
  while (Pos <= Length(S)) and (S[Pos] = ' ') do Inc(Pos);
end;
```

Is it because of some speed/memory penalty? Can someone more experienced explain me the reason/difference?

Comment: Ask the author of the code. I'd write it without the local.

Comment: A guess: The local variable can be lifted to a register but the var parameter is a memory reference, probably faster to use the register for the loop and then update memory afterwards.

Comment: @Lasse that's exactly what I guess too. Longer code but faster. Maybe someone know it for sure or I'll test it.

Comment: The version with the local variable is faster. Also moving Length(S) outside of the loop would improve performance.

Answer (score 3):

Aside possibly from performance, in well-written code, there is no difference between the two functions.

In badly written code, though, there is a huge difference. Using a local variable makes it *much* easier to reason about the correctness of the function. There's the possibility of `S` and `Pos` overlapping in memory. Do you feel like predicting how the procedure would behave if `Inc(Pos);` modifies the string's contents or length?

Using a local variable makes it easy to see *precisely* what will happen. I would certainly agree that having `S` and `Pos` overlap would be a horrible mis-use of the procedure, but the procedure's behaviour should match its specification, so either the specification should disallow such input values, or the procedure should behave as specified even in the presence of such input values. Getting the precise details of what works and what doesn't is tricky. Making the procedure work as specified in all cases is easy.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/String_Types_(Delphi)) says:

> Also, avoid passing string indexes as var parameters, because this results in inefficient code.

But I don't think that's always true. Given a simple enough example, the optimizer will do its best. In my opinion, this is a micro-optimization which shouldn't bother you in writing your code. See [Jeff Atwood](http://blog.codinghorror.com/micro-optimization-and-meatballs/):

> It just doesn't matter! It just doesn't matter!

Let's see an example:

```
procedure StringIndexByVar(const S: string; var I: integer);
begin
  I := 1;
  while I <= Length(S) do
  begin
    Write(S[I]);
    inc(I);
  end
end;

procedure StringIndexByLocal(const S: string; var I: integer);
var
  LIndex: integer;
begin
  LIndex := 1;
  while LIndex <= Length(S) do
  begin
    Write(S[LIndex]);
    inc(LIndex);
  end;
  I := LIndex;
end;
```

And this compiles in `Win32` to:

StringIndexByVar:

```
00417ACC 53               push ebx
00417ACD 56               push esi
00417ACE 8BDA             mov ebx,edx
00417AD0 8BF0             mov esi,eax
00417AD2 C70301000000     mov [ebx],$00000001
00417AD8 EB1D             jmp $00417af7
00417ADA 8B03             mov eax,[ebx]
00417ADC 0FB75446FE       movzx edx,[esi+eax*2-$02] <--- (1)
00417AE1 A18CC54100       mov eax,[$0041c58c]
00417AE6 E8E9D2FEFF       call @Write0WChar
00417AEB E824CCFEFF       call @Flush
00417AF0 E88FC6FEFF       call @_IOTest
00417AF5 FF03             inc dword ptr [ebx] <--- (2)
00417AF7 8BC6             mov eax,esi
00417AF9 E8C2F2FEFF       call @UStrLen
00417AFE 3B03             cmp eax,[ebx]
00417B00 7DD8             jnl $00417ada
00417B02 5E               pop esi
00417B03 5B               pop ebx
00417B04 C3               ret
```

StringIndexByLocal:

```
00417B08 53               push ebx
00417B09 56               push esi
00417B0A 57               push edi
00417B0B 8BFA             mov edi,edx
00417B0D 8BF0             mov esi,eax
00417B0F BB01000000       mov ebx,$00000001
00417B14 EB1A             jmp $00417b30
00417B16 A18CC54100       mov eax,[$0041c58c]
00417B1B 0FB7545EFE       movzx edx,[esi+ebx*2-$02]  <---(1)
00417B20 E8AFD2FEFF       call @Write0WChar
00417B25 E8EACBFEFF       call @Flush
00417B2A E855C6FEFF       call @_IOTest
00417B2F 43               inc ebx
00417B30 8BC6             mov eax,esi
00417B32 E889F2FEFF       call @UStrLen
00417B37 3BD8             cmp ebx,eax
00417B39 7EDB             jle $00417b16
00417B3B 891F             mov [edi],ebx
00417B3D 5F               pop edi
00417B3E 5E               pop esi
00417B3F 5B               pop ebx
00417B40 C3               ret
```

As far as I understand, the string indexing doesn't differ here, because the index is loaded into `ebx` (marked with arrow 1). Incrementing the loop counter (arrow 2) requires a memory access, but this isn't related to the string index calculation.